# Nested classes in object oriented python

Tags: python, class, oop, methods

I would like to do the following:

```py
import mymodule

m = mymodule.MyModule()

m.dosth()
# Does something

m.more.domore()
# Does more
```

The mymodule `__init__.py` file looks like this:

```py
class MyModule():
    def __init__(self):
        pass # Constructor

    def dosth(self):
        print("My module is doing something!")
    
    class more:
        def domore(self):
            print("My module is doing even more!")
```

But when I run my script, a TypeError occurres:
`TypeError: domore() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self`. How can I call methods from the class `more` without getting errors?

Comment: Why? Nested classes are rare in Python, as are static methods (though less so).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This method either needs to be static:

```
class MyModule():
    def __init__(self):
        pass # Constructor
    def dosth(self):
        print("My module is doing something!")

    class more:
        @staticmethod
        def domore():
            print("My module is doing even more!")
```

with

```
m = MyModule()
m.more.domore()
# or directly
MyModule.more.domore()
```

or you need to create an instance of `more` first:

```
m = MyModule.more()
m.domore()
```

Comment: I think adding an attribute which is an instance of the `more` class should also solve the problem, and allows to use `m.more` the way the OP intends to (from my understanding).

Comment: There isn't really enough information about why the OP wants this design to say whether an instance of `more` should be added as an attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Adding () after more solved the problem for me

```
m.more().domore()
```